# loopyWriter.run returning. connection error: desc = "transport is closing"

Tags: nodes

admission.go:98] ClusterQuotaAdmission received non-meta object *unstructured.Unstructured
client.go:360] parsed scheme: "passthrough"
passthrough.go:48] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{https://207.130.66.103:2379   0 }]  }
clientconn.go:948] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"
balancer_conn_wrappers.go:78] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc04a2d6fe0, {CONNECTING }
balancer_conn_wrappers.go:78] pickfirstBalancer: HandleSubConnStateChange: 0xc04a2d6fe0, {READY }
controlbuf.go:508] transport: `loopyWriter.run returning. connection error: desc = "transport is closing"`

Getting the following error in logs, even though the pod is in running state. After pods restart, it is getting started in one  second, and the node consumption is still 99%.